# Python: All powers of 2 from the power of 0 to 16

Tags: python, loops, math, exponent

I'm trying to program in Python so that I can print the results of 2 to the power of every number from 0 to 16. I have code below so far, but it can only print the result of 2 to the power 16 and nothing before it. How do I print the other answers with it?

---

```
n = 2
exponent = 16

while exponent < 16+1:
  n = n ** exponent
  exponent = exponent + 1
  print (n)
```

Comment: You start with `exponent = 16` maybe you should initialize `exponent` to `0`

Answer (score 6):

best way with powers of 2 is using bit-shifting on `1`, which is way faster than exponentiation in that case.

That said, I wouldn't recommend a `while` loop but rather a `for` loop, or even better: generate your list of values using a list comprehension (which avoids all the variables and undesired side effects, infinite loops because of `while`, etc...) and one-liner:

```
print([1<<exponent for exponent in range(17)])
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536]
```

Answer (score 4):

your `exponent` starts at `16`; the while loop will do one iteration only. and you are re-assigning `n` at every step of the loop...
this would work:

```
for exp in range(17):
    print(2**exp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the following changes in the code

1. `exponent` should be initially set to `0`.
2. Result should be stored in a separate variable in the loop, not in `n`

Here is the correct version of code:

```
n = 2
exponent = 0

while exponent < 16+1:
  res = n ** exponent
  exponent = exponent + 1
  print (res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the initialization of `exponent`, since you want it to go from 0 to 16, but you set it at 16 from the beginning.

`exponent = 0` should do the trick ;)

Also, be careful because you are re-assigning `n` each time in your loop. Try only printing the result instead of storing it in `n` (or use another variable).

Hope this helps!